# meridional or meridianal?

Tags: orthography

The wikipedia article on the [history of the metric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=History_of_the_metric_system&oldid=966206993) uses the adjectives meridional and meridianal (as the metre was derived from the length of the meridian passing through Paris). Which is better? According to online dictionaries, meridional is correct and meridianal does not exist. However, I suppose few readers, except geographers, have meridional in their vocabulary.

Comment: Are you asking whether it is better to use the spelling given by dictionaries? If few readers know the word, which spelling will quickly tell them what it means?

Comment: I was just wondering. I was thinking an encyclopedia article should use the dictonary spelling. But I understand your suggestion is to ignore dictionaries.

Comment: ELU deals with standard usage; if _meridional_ is listed in reputable dictionaries but not _meridianal_, that is essentially the answer as far as standard usage goes. For possible specifying usages / abstruse terminology, Geographic Information Systems.SE, which has a _terminology_ tag, seems a better place to ask.

Comment: @jkien quite the opposite: the author of the Wikepedia page clearly made a mistake, do not follow it.